# How do conversion operators work on a node that has a pointer to another node?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T value;
    Node<T>* next;

    // will this recurse till the end of the list?

    operator Node<const T>()
    {
        std::cout << "casted" << std::endl;
        return Node<const T>{value, (Node<const T>*)next};
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct X
{
    Node<T>* node;

    X(Node<T>* node) : node(node) {}

    X<const T> getConst() const
    {
        return X<const T>((Node<const T>*)node);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node<int> node3{ 0, nullptr };
    Node<int> node2{ 0, &node3  };
    Node<int> node1{ 0, &node2  };

    X<int> x(&node1);

    auto constX = x.getConst();

    std::cout << constX.node->value << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

Here I had a problem where I wanted to cast `Node<T>` to `Node<const T>`. In the conversion operator, I cast the `next` pointer to `Node<const T>*`. I thought this might recurse till the end of the list. So I tried to create a list and pass it to `X` and call `getConst` to see whether the message "casted" will be printed only one time or three times. Surprisingly it didn't print any message. How does conversion operator work? Will it recurse in this example till the end of the list? And why isn't it printing any message?

Comment: One question: do you want to make `Node` objects immutable?

Comment: [Don't use C-style casts.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/5684257) If you had used a `static_cast`, you'd have been told that your code is wrong. Also, [`std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/213977/5684257) is usually unnecessary.

Comment: @Mister_Jesus I just wanna be able to return a node of ``const T`` so that the value inside it can't be changed.

Comment: @HTNW Yes indeed, when I use static_cast it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion operator `Node<T>::operator Node<T const>()` converts an *object* of type `Node<T>` to an *object* of type `Node<T const>`. The cast `(Node<T const>*)next` in this function and the cast `(Node<T const>*)node` in `X` are not conversions between `Node` objects—they are conversions between pointers. All that happens is that the memory address of the `Node<T>` object is reinterpreted as the memory address of a `Node<T const>`. In both cases, though, there simply *isn't* a `Node<T const>` at that memory address (unless `T` is already `const`), so the pointers resulting from the casts are "invalid". The only thing you can do with the resulting pointers is cast them back to `Node<T>*` (and even that isn't guaranteed to work).

Your code a) never calls the conversion operator you defined and b) is broken. The result of `x.getConst()` contains an invalid pointer, and the access to `*constX.node` is undefined behavior. Further, if anything ever did call the conversion operator, it would create more invalid pointers. If you *really* want an `X<T const>`, then you *really* have to copy all of the `Node`s (and doing that recursively is easiest).

```
template<typename T>
Node<T>::operator Node<T const>() {
    return {value, next ? new Node<T const>(*next) : nullptr};
    //                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ recursive call
}

template<typename T>
X<T const> X<T>::getConst() const {
    return {new Node<T const>(*node)}; // I would suggest marking the constructor of X explicit
}
```

It's better to structure your code so you just *don't need* to do this expensive conversion in the first place, though.